# Excel /VBA : find constants in range with a formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to setup a formula in excel/vba that will allow me to input a range of cells and output in one cell whether or not there are any constants in that range. Its real easy to do for one cell but I cannot seem to get something working for the range. Any ideas?

thanks a lot,
Jeremy

Comment: A cell's value is a constant if it's not derived from a formula. So if I understand correctly, you want to know whether there are any cells in a range that are non-blank and non-formula?

Comment: yes by constant I mean "is not a formula". So basically the "isformula()" function from excel 2013 onwards works for a single cell but I need to adapt this so that I can apply it to a range. Practically what  I want is a formula that tells me if there are any "hardplugs" in a range of cells without having to do the F5 special highlight constants method. Thanks

Comment: @jeremy.staub- you should add the code to your question per your comment 'Its real easy to do for one cell...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for UDF that will return `True` for cells with a value and no formula:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DetectConstantInRange(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim blnResult As Boolean

    'assume false
    blnResult = False

    'iterate each cell in range
    For Each rngCell In rng
        'cell with value and no formula is constant
        If Not rngCell.HasFormula And rngCell.Value <> vbEmpty Then
            blnResult = True
            'at least one constant so exit
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rngCell

    'return result        
    DetectConstantInRange = blnResult

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robin, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Start here:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html

you need to decide which range you want to use your function on, define it,add a loop to loop through all cells in range and apply your function.